# Bind dropdown list with comma separated value for an item in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to bind an html dropdown list with model data in such a way that “PWD-SUR” will display by default when ***“Account” = SBEN or SPPY or SPLF or SWOL***

```
<div class="border col-md-2">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Account, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
        { new SelectListItem { Text = "PWD-SUR", Value = "SBEN, SPPY, SPLF, SWOL"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "LOAN", Value = "LNPR"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "LN PYMT", Value = "LNIN"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "PREM", Value = "PREM"}
        }, "Value", "Text"),"----", new {@id="ddlAccount", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Is there any way I can achieve the same?

> Note: model will contain only one account type at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if I change the code like-

```
<div class="border col-md-2">
                            @Html.DropDownList("AccountType", new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
        { new SelectListItem { Text = "PWD-SUR", Value = "SBEN, SPPY, SPLF, SWOL" },
          new SelectListItem { Text = "LOAN", Value = "LNPR"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "LN PYMT", Value = "LNIN"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "PREM", Value = "PREM"}
        }, "Value", "Text", (Model.Account == "SBEN" || Model.Account == "SPPY" || Model.Account == "SPLF" || Model.Account == "SWOL") ? "SBEN, SPPY, SPLF, SWOL" : Model.Account), new { @id = "ddlAccount", @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you try `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccountType` in place of `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Account` in previous code?

Answer (score 0):

According this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn725507%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) when you using `SelectList`, then you should specify `SelectListItem` value property which you want to set selected.

So you just need try like this:

```
<div class="border col-md-2">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Account, new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
        { new SelectListItem { Text = "PWD-SUR", Value = "SBEN, SPPY, SPLF, SWOL"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "LOAN", Value = "LNPR"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "LN PYMT", Value = "LNIN"},
          new SelectListItem { Text = "PREM", Value = "PREM"}
        }, "Value", "Text", (Model.Account == "SBEN" || Model.Account == "SPPY" || Model.Account == "SPLF" || Model.Account == "SWOL") ? "SBEN, SPPY, SPLF, SWOL" : Model.Account), new {@id="ddlAccount", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```